# Pulling long ids via reactjs truncates ids

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, grails-orm

I have a query that pulls very large numbers via react.    When I request data via curl everything comes back fine.  When I use this method:

```
   getStuff() {
        fetch(SERVER_URL + '/stuff')
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(json =>
                this.setState({stuff: json})
            )
            .catch(error => console.error('Error connecting to server: ' + error));
    }
```

I get this JSON string:

```
[{"id":1244671793987387300}]
```

when I use Curl (or any other method) I get the correct answer:

```
[{"id":1244671793987387392}]
```

Any idea how to circumvent this rounding error before react mangles it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a react problem, this is a JS issue and the biggest number ir can handle safely https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

if this is an ID it does not need to be a number, make it a string in the server and everything will be fine.

Comment: Surprising that the actual JS request was corrupted, but that might just be when its reporting in the console.       Got around it in grails by adding a marshaller that explicitly casts it to String during the request.

Comment: is not that the JS got corrupted is about the language capabilities limitations in browsers to handle big numbers.  glad this helped

Comment: The network request returning JSON was corrupted.  My typo.